# 70s-90s book series about orphaned female sorceress/book about a floating shard of a planet and a thief

Tags: story-identification

The mage's name starts with 'A' - Arrielle, Aurellia? Her parents are well to do magicians, but they die. She's raised in the country by her parents' hired man who she ends up sleeping with, possibly becoming pregnant?

She moves to the city to live at the magician head quarters, ends up sleeping with the head mage. She ends up in a gladiator ring and has to go on a quest.

It was a four book series but I never got past the first one, partly because I was young and there was some weird sex stuff, and partly because it was really dry. I think she was a fire mage. I think the book were written by a woman.

The second one was part of a pulpy series that I never read any more of, but 80s for sure? Not mainstream at all, probably a knock off of something better. *The Crystal Shard* or something. There was a thief who had to sneak into a booby trapped tomb with a princess. The premise of the book's universe was that all the planet shards were floating in a void.

Comment: Is "the second one" another book in the same series? If so, please clarify as much. If not, please ask a separate question, or this one will likely be closed for being too broad.

Comment: This definitively appears to be a question about two entirely unrelated book series

Comment: This needs to be two separate questions - one for each book series.

Comment: [Aurian by Maggie Furey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Artefacts_of_Power)? It's been too long since I read it to make an answer out of it.